# How does "Increases bonus experience" on items work?

Tags: diablo-iii

[Leoric's Signet](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/leorics-signet), [Cain's Fate](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/search?q=cain%27s%20fate&f=static) (set bonus) both give bonuses to experience worded like this:

> Increases Bonus Experience by X%

I don't have either of these to test it out, but I'm curious to see if they are worth the investment.

Do these items work like a Ruby in your helm socket, increasing the experience for monster kills by 30%?

Or is the affix read literally to mean it increases only your **bonus** experience? I.e., with a 30% ring and you have +100 xp per kill, the effect increases that to +130 xp per kill.

If the latter, what qualifies as bonus experience? Just +XP per kill? What about NV stacks? What about a ruby in your helm?

Both seem like legal interpretations of the wording, but it is a huge difference in the attractiveness of the items.

Can anyone shed some light on exactly how Leoric's Signet and the Cain's Fate set bonus work?

Comment: afaik it works exactly like a ruby.  But then, I haven't shelled out 100m to buy one to test it yet.  If it didn't, I really doubt it'd cost that much.

Comment: This is purely speculative, but if you've got 105% bonus XP from NV and a ruby, a 30% bonus to that bonus would actually be *more* attractive. `105 * 1.3 = 136.5` -- a 31% increase.

Comment: a cheaper way to test this is to see the behavior of cain's set and its interaction with a ruby

Comment: @yx Thanks, edited the question to include that item set.

Comment: @dpatchery why don't you just buy Cain's set to try it? It only costs 60k or so for 3 items. And yes, it works exactly the same as a Ruby in a helmet

Comment: @Novarg I wasn't aware of the Cain's Fate set until after I posted this question about Leoric's Signet, and haven't been on since. Is that really worth a downvote? (even if it wasn't you, I guess the downvoter had the same idea...?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works exactly the same as a helm ruby. Both items increase the "Bonus Experience %" stat on the character sheet. Despite the somewhat confusing name, this is a % increase to the base experience gained for each kill.

Comment: As you point out most % increases of really any character stat increase the base value.